# Can't get Zorba working on Windows 7 with PHP and Nginx

Tags: php, windows-7, nginx, zorba

I'm trying to install Zorba on a Windows 7 machine with the help of these [instructions](http://zorba-xquery.com/doc/zorba-2.0/zorba/html/php_windows_tutorial.html). I've completed the "Verify Zorba" section ok, but I can't complete the section "Enable Zorba extension in PHP". When I attempt to restart PHP, a Windows dialog box pops up saying;

[image: php-cgi.exe error]

**Do I *need* to compile from source?**
The instructions say to compile Zorba from source but instead have downloaded the Windows installation package from the Zorba download page. Do I also have to compile from source? Surely not?

**Missing zorba_api_wrapper.php**
The instructions say "locate the file zorba_api_wrapper.php" but I can't find a file of that name. There is a file called zorba_api.php so I've used that instead. Is that the correct file?

**php-cgi.exe**
I'm running the CGI version of PHP. I start it from the command prompt by doing;

```
php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Could that be what's causing the error dialog? I guess it's more common to have Apache start PHP. (I'm using Nginx not Apache.)

## Update

As suggested by Rodolfo, I've added `C:\Program Files\Zorba XQuery Processor 2.0.2\bin` to the `PATH` environment variable and uninstalled an older version of Zorba. Now when I try to start PHP by doing;

```
php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:9000
```

I get a different Windows dialog;

[image: Zorba Crash]

The info in the Problem Details is;

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: php-cgi.exe
  Application Version:  5.3.2.0
  Application Timestamp:    4b8ec866
  Fault Module Name:    php5ts.dll
  Fault Module Version: 5.3.2.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4b8ec7e7
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000f56c0
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

If I remove the line `extension=zorba_api.dll` from `php.ini`, PHP starts ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**>>Do I need to compile from source?**

Windows Installation Package is fine, this should work.
**>>Missing zorba_api_wrapper.php**

This is included along with zorba_api.dll in [ZORBA_INSTALL_DIR]\share\php

*The error could be caused by two reasons:*

a) zorba_api.dll is not able to locate zorba_simplestore.dll. Make sure your zorba_api.dll is able to reach zorba_simplestore.dll, the easy way is through PATH environment variable.
b) you have an older zorba_api.dll not related to a newer zorba_simplestore.dll. Make sure you don't have an older version of zorba colliding with your current version.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've uninstalled an old version of Zorba and added Zorba to the PATH environment variable, but now I get a different error. I've updated my OP with the details.

Answer (score 0):

The error, **Fault Module Name:    php5ts.dll**, while starting the Apache server is a known date bug (thread safety issue).

The work around was to modify httpd.conf as follows:

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/PHP"
# added
Loadfile "C:/PHP/php5ts.dll" 
Loadfile "C:/PHP/libpq.dll"
```

See this [PHP Bug Report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51298) for more detail

Answer (score 0):

In my case compile option wasn't macth bettween zorba_api.dll and PHP.
Then I cange PHP from VC6 to VC9.

But be sure If you use Apache, Apache also has to change to the virsion which let work PHP-VC9.

[PHP can't initialize zorba_api's module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990912/php-cant-initialize-zorba-apis-module)