# PHP can't initialize zorba_api's module

Tags: php, windows, zorba

Dose anyone know how to fix this error?

I installed zorba and it worked well like bellow.

```
C: \>zorba -q 1+1

< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

2
C:\ >
```

Then I changed PHP.ini to add extension module .

```
extension=zorba_api.dll
```

Then tied restart Apache but Apache didn't start.

I could't get any messages from Apache logs,

but I got messages If I tried this PHP operation

```
C: \>php -v

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: zorba_api: Unable to initialize module

Module compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC9

PHP    compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC6

These options need to match

 in Unknown on line 0

PHP 5.3.4 (cli) (built: Dec  9 2010 21:37:21)

Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group

Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

C:\>
```

The massage said compile option isn't match between Module and PHP.

I guess I need zorba_api compiled with VC6.
But How can I get it? Where can I take it?

I use followin products

Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Apache2.2.17

PHP-5.3.4 VC6ts

zorba 2.1.00

Comment: I solve this problem.I change PHP-VC6 to PHP-VC9 to match compile potion betwwen zorba. Alse I had to change apache to activate PHP-VC9 from Apache Lounge site.And setup Runtime for VC++ 2008,2010.Finally,zolba worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to <del>compile Zorba with VC6 or</del>  compile Zorba with any VS Version (at your own risk) but changing the signature to VC6.
*Update: Zorba doesn't support VC6 since it uses some features from C++0x.*

Comment: I know I can get it by this way but I don't have VC6 and VS ,and I meant I've been looking for Zorba compiled with VC6 somewhere in internet web site.

Comment: Sorry, Zorba can't compile with VC6, also, PHP is not supporting VC6 anymore. The way to go should be to upgrade all your systems compiled with VC9, this isn't bad as it sounds, in fact, VC9 has many performance improvements that will make your system to run faster, you can get Apache compiled in VC9 with appropiate handlers for PHP from: www.apachelounge.com