# Can´t get Zorba Java API to work under Win XP

Tags: xquery, zorba

Has anyone experience with the Zorba Java API, I can´t get it to work. At the moment I´m stuck with an

```
1,144: static error [err:XQST0059]: "http://www.zorba-xquery.com/modules/xml-options": target namespace not found for schema/module "http://www.zorba-xquery.com/modules/xml-options.xsd": Could not create stream resource
```

error whenever I try to create a XmlDataManager instance with Zorba 2.6.0.

Best regards,
Chris

Comment: I ran Dependency Walker, it gave me these:

Comment: Don´t know if connected, how can i get rid of these? Ran vcredist_x86 didnt help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get Zorba working on Windows 7 with PHP and Nginx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650585/cant-get-zorba-working-on-windows-7-with-php-and-nginx)